# Dynamic data to HTML table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I tried to create HTML table with Javascript function with JQuery **.append** method. My problem is `StockNo` , `ShortName` , `UOM` and `Balance` data are **undefined** when first time append data in HTML table.

It's ok when I trace in Javascript or alert in `GenerateTable` function. I don't know how to solve that issue. Please show me right directly !!!

**In view**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Stock,
     new SelectList(ViewBag.StockVMs, "ID", "Name"), "--Select Stock--",
     new
         {
            @class = " form-control input-ms",
            id = "ddlStock",
            @required = "required"
         })
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="number" placeholder="0" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtPrice" name="Price" onchange="calAmount()" required />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="number" placeholder="0" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtQuantity" name="Quantity" onchange="calAmount()" required />
</div>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" value="Add" onclick="Add()"/>
<tbody id="tblPurchaseItem"></tbody>
```

**In javascript file**

```
function Add () {
    BindItemEntity();    
    GenerateTable();
};

function BindItemEntity() {   
    PurchaseItemEntity = {};
    var ID = $('#ddlStock').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/PurchaseOrder/Stock?id="+ ID,
        success: function (data) {
            PurchaseItemEntity.StockNo = data.StockNo;
            PurchaseItemEntity.ShortName = data.ShortName;
            PurchaseItemEntity.UOM = data.UOM;
            PurchaseItemEntity.Balance = 1;
        }
    });
    PurchaseItemEntity.PurchaseItemID = Id;
    PurchaseItemEntity.StockID = $('#ddlStock').val();
    PurchaseItemEntity.Price = $('#txtPrice').val();
    PurchaseItemEntity.Quantity = $('#txtQuantity').val();
    PurchaseItemEntity.Amount = $('#hidAmount').val();
    PurchaseItemCollection.push(PurchaseItemEntity);
    Id = Id + 1;
}

function GenerateTable() {
    console.log(PurchaseItemCollection)
    TotalAmount = 0;
    if (PurchaseItemCollection.length > 0) {
        var amount;
        $('#tblPurchaseItem').empty();
        $.each(PurchaseItemCollection, function (index, value) { 
            //alert("Hi");
            $('#tblPurchaseItem').append(
            '<tr>' +
                      '<td><p style="font-size:small;">' + value.PurchaseItemID + '</p></td>' +
                      '<td><p style="font-size:small;">' + value.StockNo + '</p></td>' +
                      '<td><p style="font-size:small;">' + value.ShortName + '</p></td>' +
                      '<td><p style="font-size:small;">' + value.UOM + '</p></td>' +
                      '<td><p style="font-size:small;">' + value.Balance + '</p></td>' +
                      '<td style="text-align:right;">' + parseFloat(value.Price) + '</td>' +
                      '<td style="text-align:right;">' + value.Quantity + '</td>' +
                      '<td style="text-align:right;">' + parseFloat(value.Amount) + '</td>' +
                     '<td><div class="btn-group"><input type="button" id="tblBtnEdit" data-Id="' + value.PurchaseItemID + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" value="Edit" /><input type="button" data-Id="' + value.PurchaseItemID + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" id="tblBtnDelete" value="Delete"  /></div></td>' +
                      '</tr>');
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#tblPurchaseItem').empty();
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Stock(string id)
        {
            var data = db.StockDMs.Find(id);
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: besides of your question, an opening `<table>` tag is missing

Comment: Ajax is async - your `PurchaseItemCollection.push(PurchaseItemEntity);` line of code executes before the ajax `success` callback. All the code for generating an item and adding it to the array need to be inside the `success` callback

Comment: Use `async:false` in your Ajax call.

Comment: @manikantgautam - that is dreadful advice! Never use `async:false`

Comment: But why are you generating the table again everytime you add an item instead of just appending the new row to the table.

Comment: Please tell me !! how to repair my code.

Comment: As I noted in the comment above - the 7 lines of code starting with `PurchaseItemEntity.PurchaseItemID = Id;` need to be inside the `success: function (data) {`

Comment: I got it. Thank !!!

Comment: Thank manikant gautam !!! I use async:false in my ajax call . It's ok !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use async false in your ajax call :

```
function BindItemEntity() {   
    PurchaseItemEntity = {};
    var ID = $('#ddlStock').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async:false, /* here */
        url: "/PurchaseOrder/Stock?id="+ ID,
        success: function (data) {
            PurchaseItemEntity.StockNo = data.StockNo;
            PurchaseItemEntity.ShortName = data.ShortName;
            PurchaseItemEntity.UOM = data.UOM;
            PurchaseItemEntity.Balance = 1;
        }
    });
    PurchaseItemEntity.PurchaseItemID = Id;
    PurchaseItemEntity.StockID = $('#ddlStock').val();
    PurchaseItemEntity.Price = $('#txtPrice').val();
    PurchaseItemEntity.Quantity = $('#txtQuantity').val();
    PurchaseItemEntity.Amount = $('#hidAmount').val();
    PurchaseItemCollection.push(PurchaseItemEntity);
    Id = Id + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for datatables, which is the library of JQ to render tables. They have ajax based table in which you can insert values inside of on success function and no need of append data. You can also apply sort, search and filters too. Have a look, 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html